# Corrupted package over async TCP in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, network-programming, tcpclient

I am in a bit of pickle here. For a while I am trying to understand what am I doing wrong with async TCP.

I have two machines over the network sending data from A -> B. I calculate and print the MD5 of my `byte[]` on both machines before sending and just after receiving.

From time to time, lets say around 3 seconds, the machine that receives the message gets a corrupted package (different MD5). If I am running both programs on localhost this does not occurs.

As far as I know this should not happen in TCP since it ensures delivery and package integrity (right?). The sending code is just a while loop with a sleep in it for now.

Here is the receiving end:

```
            //We are receiving the package but don't know the size yet
            //This -if- is here just to be safe...
            if (state.RecvBytesCount < 4)
            {
                handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, state.RecvBytesCount-1, 4 - state.RecvBytesCount, 0, ReadHandler,
                    state);
            }
            //Serialized bson contains the size in the first 4 bytes.
            if (state.RecvBytesCount == 4)
            {
                state.TotalPackageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.Buffer, 0);

                state.ResetBuffer(state.TotalPackageSize);
                var length  = BitConverter.GetBytes(state.TotalPackageSize);
                state.Buffer[0] = length[0];
                state.Buffer[1] = length[1];
                state.Buffer[2] = length[2];
                state.Buffer[3] = length[3];
                //Keep reading...
                semaphore.Release();
                handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 4, state.TotalPackageSize - 4, 0, ReadHandler,
                    state);
            }

           //we already know the package size
            else
            {
                //Not done yet
                if (state.RecvBytesCount < state.TotalPackageSize - 4)
                {
                    handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, state.RecvBytesCount - 1,
                        state.TotalPackageSize - state.RecvBytesCount, 0, ReadHandler, state);
                    semaphore.Release();
                }
                else
                {
                    PrintMD5(state.Buffer);
                    byte[] workingBuffer = new byte[state.Buffer.Length];
                    //TODO: Make the working buffer the size of the received package
                    Array.Copy(state.Buffer,workingBuffer,state.Buffer.Length);
                    HandleMessage(workingBuffer, state);
                    //Prep to receive another package
                    state.ResetBuffer();
                    state.RecvBytesCount = 0;
                    semaphore.Release();
                    handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, 4, 0,
                        ReadHandler, state);
                }
             }
```

In the `HandleMessage` method I've try to deserialize the data but when it is corrupted it throws and exception. I have a breakpoint there that lets me stop the code and inspect the MD5.

Comment: Are handling endianess properly?

Comment: it is virtually certain that TCP is continuing to work fine, and the issue here is to do with frames. It is notoriously hard to debug code like this in isolation, but: I suggest writing out the received buffer in every receive while you analyse what is going on. You mention it happens intermittently; that almost certainly means frame length issues, perhaps when a frame is split over multiple packets, or multiple frames are joined into a single packet.

Comment: @MichaelK endianess is fine, both machines are the same architecture. If it was and endianess problem it would always fail but it is only some times

Comment: Hi @MarcGravell that's sounds like a possible path. One thing that is worth mentioning, right now I am sending at 30ms intervals and I get one problem at ~3s. If I increase the delay to 100ms then the error does not occurs. Because the MD5 is different I assume something is going wrong when I reconstruct the package but I am not sure were the problem could be.

Comment: @JulianoFranz well... what if `state.RecvBytesCount > state.TotalPackageSize - 4`? i.e. multiple frames in one receive?

Comment: This might not help you concretely but the way this code is writing is so complicated that it is very hard to make correct. I have experience with sockets and I would have a very hard time maintaining this. If you rewrite this with async and await then the new code might be so simple that the bug just goes away in the process. Get rid of the callback hell.

Comment: @MarcGravell that cannot happen (should not?) because I call the `beginReceive` with only whats left to receive to complete the package in the size parameter: `totalPackageSize - RecvBytesCount`. The question now is: does the size in `BeginReceive` ensures that I will not receive more than the value set there?

Comment: Hi @usr I've actually followed microsoft example on asynchronous server. If you do have another source I will deferentially take a look a it but generally I do refactoring once the code is working the way its supposed to be

Comment: So you followed Microsofts example. That explains why the code is such a mess. (lol) The MSDN socket code is soooo bad. These tutorials have inflicted so much pain on unsuspecting socket novices. Good socket code is actually fairly simple. Ideally, you just rewrite it with await. The code will look like normal synchronous code and you will be able to understand it.

Comment: @usr resurrecting this thread. I've did implemented using tasks and I still have the same problem, actually it is worse as I am having errors with only 3 messages at 10ms each. I am lost. I wonder if I should open a new thread here with they new code. Maybe my problem is in the send part?

Comment: What seems to be happening is that instead of getting messages A, B, C, D I get messages A, B, CD, E ,... If I set the buffer size for the exact amount of the package I am sending everything works like a charm (but the size will be dynamic)

Comment: By typing my last comment I've got the solution in my head. I'll post an answer soon =]